# Change submit button value

Tags: javascript, ajax

It may take a long time to complete the call.php and get the return value, how can I change the submit button's value to "Processing … " while the call.php is being executed?

Submit button with id "submit_btn", there is no change to the script

`$('#submit_btn').val('Processing …')`

AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit_btn').val('Processing ...');
      $.ajax({
        cache: false, 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
        complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('#submit_btn').val('Create');
      }});
      return false;
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<form action="call.php" method="POST" id="form1" name="form1">
        <input type="text" name="campname" id="campname">
        <textarea id="longdesc" name="longdesc"></textarea>
        <input type="text" name="vercode" id="vercode" />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit_btn" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple form from single HTML file,  $('#submit_btn').val('Processing …').button('refresh'); is work but NOT in multiple jQuery page.

HTML

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" id="form1" name="form1">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
        <input type="button" value="Button" name="btn01" id="btn01" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit_btn').val('Processing …').button('refresh');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
            complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('#submit_btn').val('Submit').button('refresh');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo page: http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/C6kzr/

For multiple jQuery page, **$('#submit_btn').prev().text("Processing …")** must be used instead.

HTML

```
<!-- HOME Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">   <a href="#menu" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-left">Menu</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Panel Page ---->
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-display="overlay">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#formpage" data-prefetch="false">Goto Form Page</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <p><a data-role="button" data-rel="close">Close</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Form Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="formpage" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="test.php" method="POST" id="form1" name="form1">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
                <input type="button" value="Button" name="btn01" id="btn01" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#submit_btn').prev().text("Processing ...").delay( 1000 );
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
            complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('#submit_btn').prev().text('Submit');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo page: http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/V5mSv/

Comment: It's similar to my code except the delay part which I advice you not to use(because you can't relay on the user's internet speed :D) and check the @r3mus answer with the beforeSend option. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you are right, the delay I use here just for delay the change of the text to the button. It is too fast to change back to 'Submit' without delay.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure, but why don't try to change the value with jQuery on click?

Something like:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){
   $(this).val("your value")
})
```

... or just change in your code the **submit** with **click** :)

**--------------EDIT(based on the author code)----------------**

The value of the button don't change because the jquery you use style the basic submit input by applying a span over it. So on click You will have to change the text in this span.

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Uw9A6/1/)

Comment: The click function would not work well here. If a user pressed the enter button to submit the form, this would never change the value of the button.

Comment: @Justin - ah, I have to ckeck that but if it is not working then you can use the Enter key event...but it is too lame...The Ajax beforeSend option is maybe the best solution the author could get.

Comment: @Justin - I made a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/6zjCZ/1/. The enter button change the value too :)

Comment: NoSense's solution is work when only work with 1.10.2/jquery.min.js, thanks a lot. 

After I apply jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js, then the value of submit button cannot be change.

Demo on http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/Uw9A6/

Comment: I've changed my answer :)

Comment: Thanks NoSense, you guide me the way to do the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$ajax`'s `beforeSend` option:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false, 
    type: "POST", 
    beforeSend: function() { ... },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val('Processing ...'); // this did the trices 
      $.ajax({
        cache: false, 
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
        complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $('#submit_btn').val('Create');
      }});
      return false;
  });
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/6zjCZ/)

Answer (score 0):

For my this was the one that worked in a page with many forms with the same name and id

```
$(this).find("#submit").val("Saved");
```